# equivalent in sass of iscolor in less

Tags: sass, less

I would like to know if there is a way to emulate the function iscolor present in less in sass / scss.
I haven't find this function inside the documentation but I hope that there is a way to do it.

My check in less is like this:

```
.myfunction(@color) when (iscolor(@color)){
    color:@color;
}
```

sass

```
@mixin myfunction($color){
   //function to check if color is a real color
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs have a wealth of information (see: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html)

```
@mixin myfunction($color){ // functions and mixins are very differen't things
    @if type-of($color) == color {
        @debug yep;
    }
}
```

Comment: uhm interesting, I haven't thought that there is the type color! Great thanks for the help